# Nightwatch.js won't get URL on server OS

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I have a test that works fine on my machine, but I'm running into problems when I try to move it to the server OS (Windows Server 2008 specifically). All the test really needs to do is load up each URL from a file. When I run it on the server os, it only loads a blank page. But I know it's reading the file, because I can console.log out the list of URLs, and also if my file has 5 lines, it will say 5 tests failed.

A different test I tried which doesn't read from a file, which is just given an array of a few URLs to read through works fine, by the way

Any idea what's going on? Here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var i = 0;
var errorlog = "";


module.exports = {

    'Person Page Test w/ txt file' : function (browser) {
        //iterates through excel sheet testing each URL
            fs.readFileSync('PersonPageUrls.txt').toString().split('\n').forEach(function (line) { 

                var url = line;
                i++;
                console.log(url);
                browser
                    .url(url)
                    .saveScreenshot('tests/PersonPage/screenshots/PersonPage' + i + '.png')
                    .waitForElementVisible('button[class=Person__readMoreButton___28toI]', 3000, false, function(result) {
                        if (!result.value) {
                            //if test fails, add to error log string
                            browser.url(function(currentUrl){
                                console.log();
                                errorlog = errorlog + "Test fail on: " + currentUrl.value + "\r\n";
                            }); 
                        }
                    });

            });
    browser.end()
    }       
};
```

and my nightwatch.json

```
{
"src_folders" : ["tests"],
"output_folder" : "reports",
"custom_commands_path" : "",
"custom_assertions_path" : "",
"page_objects_path" : "",
"globals_path" : "",



"selenium" : {
  "start_process" : true,
  "server_path" : "selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar",
  "log_path" : "",
  "host" : "127.0.0.1",
  "port" : 4444,
  "cli_args" : {
    "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
    "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
  }
},

"test_settings" : {
  "default" : {
    "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
    "selenium_port"  : 4444,
    "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
    "silent": true,
    "screenshots" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "on_failure" : true,
      "on_error" : true,
      "on_success" : true,
      "path" : ""
    },
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "javascriptEnabled": true,
      "acceptSslCerts": true
    }
  },

  "chrome" : {
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "javascriptEnabled": true,
      "acceptSslCerts": true
    }
  }
}
```

}

Heres the output I get (running on a 2 line text file) (if it isn't obvious, I replaced the real URLs it prints with ~~~~. But it does print the urls):

```
D:\NightwatchProjects>nightwatch -t tests/PersonPage/personpagetxt.js
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  3004

[Person Page\personpagetxt] Test Suite
======================================

Running:  Person Page Test w/ txt file
~~my url 1 ~~
~~my url 2~~
 ? Timed out while waiting for element <button[class=Person__readMoreButton___28
toI]> to be present for 3000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: not fo
und
    at D:\NightwatchProjects\tests\PersonPage\personpagetxt.js:26:8
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.module.exports.Person Page Test w/ txt file (D:\NightwatchProjects
\tests\PersonPage\personpagetxt.js:18:66)
    at Module.call (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch
\lib\runner\module.js:63:34)
    at C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\t
estcase.js:97:29
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\
node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\nightwatch\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\nightwatch\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\node_modules
\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\n
ode_modules\q\q.js:137:13)

 ? Timed out while waiting for element <button[class=Person__readMoreButton___28
toI]> to be present for 3000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: not fo
und
    at D:\NightwatchProjects\tests\PersonPage\personpagetxt.js:26:8
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.module.exports.Person Page Test w/ txt file (D:\NightwatchProjects
\tests\PersonPage\personpagetxt.js:18:66)
    at Module.call (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch
\lib\runner\module.js:63:34)
    at C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\t
estcase.js:97:29
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\
node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\nightwatch\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\nightwatch\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\node_modules
\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nightwatch\n
ode_modules\q\q.js:137:13)


FAILED:  2 assertions failed (11.389s)
Test fail on: about:blank
Test fail on: about:blank


----------------------------------------------------
TEST FAILURE: 2 assertions failed, 0 passed (11.53s)
 ? PersonPage\personpagetxt
   - Person Page Test w/ txt file
     Timed out while waiting for element <button[class=Person__readMoreButton___
28toI]> to be present for 3000 milliseconds. - Expected "visible" but got: "not
found"
     Timed out while waiting for element <button[class=Person__readMoreButton___
28toI]> to be present for 3000 milliseconds. - Expected "visible" but got: "not
found"


D:\NightwatchProjects>
```

Comment: what OS are you referring to? ubuntu?

Comment: Windows, sorry, I'll edit my question also

Comment: gotcha; and there's no stacktrace or any error being thrown?

Comment: Only the error saying the element can't be found.

Comment: Can you include that, too? All info is helpful

Comment: added it to the question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98362/discussion-between-markthethomas-and-sarah).